# How to loop over Soundcloud resolve api without calling too many times per second?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I have an array of soundcloud track urls that I need to get the streaming url for (called stream_url).  I know that resolve allows you to call the api with only a url and get info on it (it returns stream_url in the json).

How do I loop over a list of track urls to return the stream_url for each?  How do I do so in a way that I don't hammer their servers with excessive api calls?  I have a long list of track urls.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a compelling reason not to, do expensive API calls only right before the user needs the data. So if you have a list and don't need the result unless the user tries to stream the track, then simply call the API as part of the "loading" and package it in with the initial startup lag time.

If for some reason you always need each and every value then you should throttle the calls and just load a set few at a time. For example maybe you load 5, wait for those to finish and go on top the next 5.

Comment: Wouldn't it be far less expensive to call the array once than to have many users calling it each time?  Your suggestion would add up to more total calls

Comment: You said JavaScript, so I asked we were talking client-side solutions. JavaScript will run once per client visit no matter the approach. If you have a server-side component involved as well, it absolutely makes sense to at the very least cache the results, but as far as I know SoundCloud only allows getting the stream_URL one at a time due to how the expect it would be used.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what input you have at the start. Since you say you're using the resolve api, I assume you have the permalinks of several tracks, eg:

```
https://soundcloud.com/someuser/sometrack
https://soundcloud.com/anotheruser/anothertrack
```

What I'd suggest doing is resolving each of those urls exactly once and storing the result. Not all the fields will be valid forever (that is, the author might change the title of the track or something, play counts will be out of date very soon, etc), but you will get the id of the track which is fixed.

From there, you could actually construct the `stream_url` yourself, since it's a fixed format: `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/:id/stream`. Just substitute the id into each and you're away.

If you do go down this path and only need the id of each of the tracks, you could even make it a little more efficient when using the resolve endpoint by not following the 302 and instead parsing the id out of the location returned:

```
curl https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve\?url\=http://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood\&client_id\=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
{"status":"302 - Found","location":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/293?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"}
```

Here, you can see it resolves to track with id 293.